# Unable to install ipa file using testflight or diwali in xcode 4.5.1 and ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, testflight

Hy.

I have developed an IOS app in version 5.1 and xcode 4.5.1. After completing the app when I try to run it in the device using ad hoc distribution, the app is unable to install on device.
It shows popup "Unable to download application. ' could not be downloaded at this time'".

I have added distribution and developer certificate and it does not give any such alert when installing directly from the xcode but the problem occurs only when installing app from the testflight.

Could someone tell me where I m making a mistake.

Comment: I'm having this issue too, right now. I wonder if Apple is generating bad provisioning profiles mometarily.

Comment: Did you check that TestFlight is up and running? They post some status info e.g. at [TestFlightApp twitter](https://twitter.com/testflightapp) account.

Comment: Go to Product -> Edit Schema -> Build Configuration try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Product -> Edit Schema -> Build Configuration

Change Debug to Release and try it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must Archive the application using your AdHoc Distribution Cert, then from the Archives tab of the Organizer click Distribute and again select your AdHoc cert. The .ipa that this produces is what must be uploaded to TestFlight and you must authorize your device through TestFlight. Here's some tutorials that will help:

[Create and Upload an IPA to TestFlight](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413)

[Setting up Permissions for Distribution on TestFlight](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829819-setting-up-permissions-distribution)

If your IPA and permissions are all correct then according to [this article](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829652-received-an-unable-to-download-application-message-what-does-this-mean-) the error could be related to one of many other factors:

- Device storage is full
- The provisioning profile is a developer provisioning profile
- The ad hoc distribution provisioning profile is corrupted and the device is having an issue with it.
- The device was restored from a backup and is causing a conflict for over-the-air distribution
- There was a network timeout

See the referenced article for details on how to get a console log on the device. If you still are unable to resolve the issue then edit your question and include the relevant parts of the console log from the device.

Comment: sorry but i have do this thing and also create ipa successfully and problem is still occure..my other app is working ...